# AngularJS and Jasmine testing controller method calling factory method with $http

Tags: angularjs, controller, tdd, jasmine

I know there are many similar questions, but none of them applies to the same scenario - so please do NOT mark it as duplicate.

I'm trying to figure out how to perform the test of the controller method, which calls the method of the injected factory service, that performs the $http call and returns the json array.

Here's what I've got:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

.factory('callsFact', function($http) {

    var urlWrite = 'write.php';

    return {

        write : function(content) {

            return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: urlWrite,
                data: "content=" + content,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            });

        }

      };

})

.controller('ReadWriteCtrl', function($scope, callsFact) {

    $scope.data = [];

    $scope.content = 'Some content';

    $scope.add = function() {

        callsFact.write($scope.content).success(function(data) {

            $scope.data.push({ id : data.id, content : $scope.content });

        });

    };

});
```

Now, here's where I got with the test as I'm not quite sure how to do it (and please do not criticize - I'm looking for some help):

```
describe('ReadWriteCtrl tests', function() {

    var $scope,
        callsFact;



    beforeEach(function() {

        module('myApp');

        inject(function($rootScope, _callsFact_) {

            $scope = $rootScope.$new();
            callsFact = _callsFact_;

        });

    });


    it('should add new content', inject(function($controller) {

        $controller('ReadWriteCtrl', {

            $scope : $scope,
            callsFact : callsFact

        });


        $scope.data = [];

        $scope.content = 'Some message';

        $scope.add();

        expect($scope.data.length).toBe(1);


    }));

});
```

Just to clarify - I'm trying to figure out how I could test the add() method of the ReadWriteCtrl.

Answer (score 0):

So in that case you can use a mocked out version of `callsFact`

```
var mockPromise = {success: function(f){f({id:1})}};
var mockCallsFact = spyOn({}, 'add').andReturn(mockPromise);
$controller('ReadWriteCtrl', {

        $scope : $scope,
        callsFact : mockCallsFact

    });
```

Then you can also include the assertion:

```
expect(mockCallsFact.add).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

You can also use the mock `httpBackend', but I favor mocking out the the dependencies this way.